# How to make a stateless mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to make a mysql docker image that imports some initial data in the build process.

Afterwards, when used in a container, the container stays stateless, meaning the data added while the container is running does not survive destroying/starting the container again but the inital data is still there.

Is this possible? How would I a setup such an image and container?

Comment: Just write a `Dockerfile` FROM the MySQL image which execute a script or a SQL command to retrieve initial data into the containers. When your image is ready, you just have to launch a container (`docker run myMySQLImage`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating the MySQL tables as needed in a SQL script, or directly in a local MySQL instance and exporting them to a file.

With this file in hand, create a Dockerfile which builds on the MySQL container.  Add to this another entrypoint script which injects the SQL script into the database.

You don't write anything about mounting volumes. You may want a data volume for the database or configure MySQL for keeping everything in memory.

For added "statelessness" you may want to DROP all tables in your SQL script too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a multi-stage build:

```
FROM mysql:5.7 as builder

# needed for intialization
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword

ADD initialize.aql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# That file does the DB initialization but also runs mysql daemon, by removing the last line it will only init
RUN ["sed", "-i", "s/exec \"$@\"/echo \"not running $@\"/", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "mysqld", "--datadir", "/initialized-db"]

FROM mysql:5.7

COPY --from=builder /initialized-db /var/lib/mysql
```

You can put your initialization scripts in initialize.sql (or choose a different way to initialize your database).

The resulting image is a database that is already initialised. You can use it and throw it away as you like.

You can also use this process to create different images (tag them differently) for different use cases.

Hope this answers your question.